# iterate through paths stored in a list then delete them

Tags: c#, database, search

wanted to ask if it is possible to delete certain files after an advanced search with the use of some sort of batch, in C#.
I believe I can do something like:

1. search for the files
2. store the files in a `listbox` , `dataGridView`or a `checkedlistbox` (for certain deletion or maybe all)
3. store them afterwards in a List<> , or a file *.txt
4. script to delete them, or use C# (delete them programmatically)

My questions / points of interest are:

a) is the search for a file more optimized when searching DB fields (after doing some search for files in directories then storing in DB), or through iterating/ looping through directories again? (think first one) will there be any trouble storing paths in  DB tables?

b) at 3. I'm not sure how to store long paths..but I'll figure it out...can anyone tell me if there might be some issues with long paths storage?

c) how could I picture the deletion process?

d) anyone know scripting so I could delete them fom the *.txt file?

e) at 4. will the next code be enough to del them programmatically":

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\");
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
  File.Delete(filePath);
```

where the path is taken from DB..

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like you need a database. After you have performed the search you already know the file names to delete and this is all you need.

There is no concerns about storing long paths using either List<> or a text file. The are stored exactly the same as short paths.

Why do you need to picture the deletion process? Is there something in particular you do not understand about it? Deletion process is basically an API call that tells the file system that a file it stores is no longer exists. The file system makes a note of this and frees space / does not surface this file on any subsequent request. - this is how I picture it.

Yes, you can delete them based on either List<> or a text file.

The code that you gave will delete all the files from c:\MyDir\ If this is all you want, then this is enough (given the application has correct permissions and files are not locked by another process).

Here are some helpful references to answer you further questions:

How to delete a file:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx

How to write to a text file 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8bh11f1k.aspx

How to iterate through an array 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ts69ce3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

How to iterate through a collection
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzc4yayd%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

You can delete the files from your C# code, you don't need cmd.exe for this.

Comment: thanks for your answer. ..have any knowledge how to do it programmatically in C#? I also must  into how to delete even files locked (unlock them first I suppose..) I was going to delete a looooot of files froma small network, but not all of them, although   @zespri

Comment: @Paradigm: yes. what would you like to know in particular?

Comment: I would like to know how to delete the paths (selected from a checkbox) then stored in a .txt file, then to iterate through them programatically in C# (and by using cmd.exe to delete all files in the paths from .txt, I guess in a script maybe)..sorry for slow on coding and when searching for it didn't find something suiting...@zespri